# sending mail from my account. Not webhosts

Tags: php, email, message

I got a contact form that succesfully sends emails to me.

heres the extract:

```
$_POST['message'] = wordwrap($_POST['message'], 70);
mail ('myemail@test.com', $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message'] , $_POST['email']);
echo "<div class='registertext'>Your email was succesfully sent to a member of the administration team. Please wait 24 hours for as to reply and ensure you check your junk mail!<br />To login please click <a href='login.php'>here</a></div>";
```

The issue I have is, the email gets sent from my host. Not a email I want to specify. How would I overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify it in the email headers:

```
$recipient = "recipient@test.com";
    $from      = "You@yoursite.com";
    $replyTo   = "You@yoursite.com";
    $subject   = "Hi!";
    $text      = "<p>This is a test!<p>";

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
      ."Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"
      ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n"
      ."From: =?UTF-8?B?". base64_encode([Your Name]) ."?= <$from>\r\n"
      ."Reply-To: $replyTo\r\n"
      ."X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion();

    //send it!
    if (mail($recipients, $subject, $text, $headers, "-f $from")){
        echo "sent";
        } else {
           echo "did not send";
        };
```

but there's a good chance it will get caught be SPAM filters. Your best bet in this case would be to use a PHP mailing library that handles SMTP emailing and uses your actual account to send mail (there are several packages that can handle this for you: [Pear Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/redirected), and [PHP Mailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/) amongst others.

Comment: Sorry...this is like my 8th day in PHP. this spam filter? Isit that of my webhost. Also thanks for your input! Managed to learn a bit :)

Comment: The recipient's email server likely checks incoming mail against blacklists, and has algorithms for detecting mail that is SPAM, including reverse DNS lookups to detect whether the sending server is an authorized agent for that domain's email. SMTP will use your actual email server to send the mail by "logging in" and sending the email (like what Outlook does when you configure and SMTP server)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PEAR mail which will use a SMTP account. Here is some code from my mail form I use

```
        $from = "Name <webmaster@domain.com>";
        $to = "Name <address@domain.com>";
        $subject = "Subject";
        $body = 'A message!';

        $host = "ssl://domain.com";
        $port = "465";
        $username = "username";
        $password = "password";

        $headers = array ('From' => $from,
                          'To' => $to,
                          'Subject' => $subject);
        $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
                              array ('host' => $host,
                                     'port' => $port,
                                     'auth' => true,
                                     'username' => $username,
                                     'password' => $password));

        $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

        if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
            echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
        } else {
            echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
        }
```